# Error in view with foreach when get array of object in laravel 5.4 Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, properties, laravel-5.3

I first learn laravel framework and now I practice with one-to-one relationship but I have problem when I want to get the property of related object. Ex: I have a student table that all that student must has only one passport. And I want to list all student property like (id, name, gender, email, address and passport_number) in table in html. Below is my Controller, Model and Migration. And if I want to return it as json object how can I do? Thanks u!

**student migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**student class**

```
class Student extends Model{
  public function passport()
  {
        return $this->hasOne(Passport::class)
  }
}
```

**passport migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('passports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('number')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**passport model**

```
public function student(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, "student_id");
}
```

**student controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $students  = Student::all();
    return view('student.home', compact('students'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->gender}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->passport->number }}</td>
        <td>{{$student->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->address}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```